# How to read integer array values coming in JSON parameter in Postgres - Missing "]" after array dimensions

Tags: postgresql, json

I'm very new to Postgres and trying to insert the array integer values into a table as multiple rows.

Here is the json string

```
'{   
  
"types": [3,6]
 
}'
```

trying to read and insert the types into a table with an error

```
INSERT INTO table(type) SELECT unnest(par_json->'types'::int[])
```

**ERROR:  malformed array literal: "types"
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.**

Appreciate your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because JSONB arrays are not formatted the same way as normal integer arrays (jsnob use `[]` while int[] uses `{}`).

What you need here is the `jsonb_array_elements_text` function. I recommend you read the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) on all JSON/JSONB operators and functions.

As for the solution to your question, this query will correctly "unnest" your values:

```
select x::int
from jsonb_array_elements_text('{"types": [3,6]}'::jsonb->'types') x;
```

Since the function returns `text` you have to manually cast the output to `int`.

If you'd like to convert a jsonb int array into a normal int[] in postgresql, you may use the following:

```
select array(select x::int from jsonb_array_elements_text('{"types": [3,6]}'::jsonb->'types') x);
```

You may even turn this into a function so you don't have to write this code every time yourself.

Comment: Perfect! thanks for your response.